# Wrap a CLI Java application in an Applet

Tags: java, applet

I have a CLI Java application that takes a filename as an argument, and outputs its result to STDOUT.

I don't have the source code for this application, and it performs logic that needs to be executed client-side as part of a web app.

Is it possible to create an Applet wrapper around this application, and then send input and retrieve the result via JavaScript? If so, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, though note that to redirect output streams requires a trusted applet AFAIR.